# Grey Areas surrounding hair cards on 3D model in Blender v2.70

Tags: texturing, game-engine, transparency, uv-image-editor, hair

At the moment, I am trying to find a way of getting rid of the grey areas that surround the hair cards on this 3D model, as these textures are supposed to be transparent.

They are transparent once clicked on, however a grey outline appears around each hair card when they are not selected.

This character was made with a plan for it to be exported into Unreal Engine 4.

Here is a picture, showing a Hair Card selected, with the said mesh transparent:

[image: A Hair Card selected, with the said mesh transparent]

Here is a picture, showing a Hair Card not selected, with the said mesh having a grey outline:

[image]

I have read a lot of suggestions of how to fix this, but being relatively new to blender, I don’t really know what to do or look for (stuff with nodes, attributes etc.)

If anyone has got any suggestions, feel free to drop a comment.

Comment: please provide blend file